# -[__NSCFNumber row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have checked out other answers but they don't seem to answer my question properly. Please if there is an obvious one I haven't seen, put it in the comments for me :)

What I have is a tableView that has a Realm Database as the datasource. I want to be able to delete from the source the cell that is deleted.

Here is the code:

```
func objectsForSection(section: UInt) -> RLMResults {
    let categoryName = (Category.allObjects()[section] as Category).name
    return Product.objectsWhere("productCategory.name == '\(categoryName)'")
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        var realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        let productsForSection = objectsForSection(UInt(indexPath.section)) // This returns an RLMResults
        let product = productsForSection[UInt(indexPath.row)] as Product
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        realm.deleteObject(product)
        realm.commitWriteTransaction()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

It crashes when I do the swipe across and press delete. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a line that says:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath.row], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

That passes an array with a row number, not an `NSIndexPath`.

I believe you meant:

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Just wondering why didn't it work, just so I understand fully? :) @Rob

Comment: It was expecting an array of `NSIndexPath` objects, and one of the first things it apparently tried to do is call the `row` method on that object. But you sent it a number, not an `NSIndexPath`, so when it tried to call `row` on that object, it failed.

Comment: Because it's calling an old Objective-C routine that was just expecting an `NSArray` (which Swift interprets as an array of `AnyObject`) and therefore doesn't do much type checking of its members. If this was a Swift function, it would have probably been defined as an array of `NSIndexPath` objects, and the compiler would have caught this. But not the old Cocoa API written for Objective-C...

Comment: Ok Thanks for that! One last question, will apple update all the old Cocoa API to swift or not?

Comment: I'd wager we'll see `AnyObject` references in Cocoa API for a long, long time.